# How to avoid error message window

Tags: c#

we're having an application on server instance and quite rarely, but we have out of memory exception (program is not leaking, just instance is quite small and it operates with quite big amounts of data).

That would be not a problem, as we monitor processes on that server instance and if some of the processes are not found in process list, alert email is sent.

Now the problem is with this:

[image]

That prevents process from disappearing from process list, so we don't get alert email about it's failure. Is it possible to disable this message, that if program fails on something we don't catch, it would close without user interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Windows Forms, I typically do multiple steps to prevent this message box.

First, I connect several handlers in the `Main` function:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main()
{
    Application.ThreadException +=
        application_ThreadException;

    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(
        UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
        currentDomain_UnhandledException;

    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

Those handlers are being called when an otherwise unhandled exception occurs. I would define them something like:

```
private static void application_ThreadException(
    object sender,
    ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    doHandleException(e.Exception);
}

private static void currentDomain_UnhandledException(
    object sender,
    UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    doHandleException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
}
```

The actual `doHandleException` function that is then called does the actual error handling. Usually this is logging the error and notifying the user, giving him the options to continue the application or quit it.

An example from a real-world application looks like:

```
private static void doHandleException(
    Exception e)
{
    try
    {
        Log.Instance.ErrorException(@"Exception.", e);
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format(
                @"Error during exception logging: '{0}'.", x.Message));
    }

    var form = Form.ActiveForm;
    if (form == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(buildMessage(e), 
                "MyApp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(form, buildMessage(e), 
                "MyApp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

With the helper function:

```
public static string buildMessage(Exception exception)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    while (exception != null)
    {
        result.AppendLine(exception.Message);
        result.AppendLine();
        exception = exception.InnerException;
    }

    return result.ToString().Trim();
}
```

If you are using not Windows Forms but e.g. a Console application or WPF, some handlers are not present, while others are present instead.

The idea stays the same: Subscribe to event handlers that are being called if you have no `try...catch` around your code blocks.

Personally, I try to have as few of those `try...catch` blocks as possible (ideally none).

Answer (score 2):

don't know if you can deactivate this - but I think you should not.
Find the bug/problem in your application and handle the problem with a craceful shutdown or by preventing the problem in first case.
Everything else will be a real crude workaround and I don't think your client will be pleased to have such a behavior (after all won't there be data lost? If not this has allways the buggy / not finished touch)

Answer (score 1):

You could put a global try/catch block in your program and exit the program on any unexpected exception.

Answer (score 1):

If using WPF you can try-catch the following two exceptions in your `app.xaml.cs`. There may be other/complementary exceptions to handle, but this are the two I am usually looking for:

> [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) - "This event provides notification of uncaught exceptions. It allows the application to log information about the exception before the system default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the application. If sufficient information about the state of the application is available, other actions may be undertaken — such as saving program data for later recovery. Caution is advised, because program data can become corrupted when exceptions are not handled."
>
> [Dispatcher.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.unhandledexception.aspx) - "Occurs when a thread exception is thrown and uncaught during execution of a delegate by way of Invoke or BeginInvoke."

ie:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
public App()
{
    this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += DispatcherUnhandledException;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainUnhandledException;
}

private void CurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // log and close gracefully
}


private new void DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    // log and close gracefully
}
}
```